# Problema com execução de SQL através do FORM

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, sql

**Código php:**

```
if($_REQUEST['alterarStatus']){ $alterarStatus = trataaspas($_REQUEST['alterarStatus']);}

if($alterarStatus=="aprovado"){

$SQL = "update ps set StatusTransacao='Aprovado' where Referencia = '52'";  

}elseif($alterarStatus=="completo"){
}elseif($alterarStatus=="cancelado"){
}elseif($alterarStatus=="devolvido"){
}
```

**Código JS:**

```
function alterarStatusFunction(val){
if(val =="aprovado"){
if (confirm('Tem certeza que deseja alterar o status dessa transação para APROVADO?')) {
document.formtransacoes.submit();
} else {
return false;
}
}
else if(val =="completo"){
if (confirm('Tem certeza que deseja alterar o status dessa transação para COMPLETO?')) {
document.formtransacoes.submit();
} else {
return false;
}
}
else if(val =="cancelado"){
if (confirm('Tem certeza que deseja alterar o status dessa transação para CANCELADO?')) {
document.formtransacoes.submit();
} else {
return false;
}
}
else if(val =="devolvido"){
if (confirm('Tem certeza que deseja alterar o status dessa transação para DEVOLVIDO?')) {
document.formtransacoes.submit();
} else {
return false;
}
}
}
```

**Código HTML:**

```
<form name="formtransacoes" id="formtransacoes" action="" method="post">
<?
while($obj = mysqli_fetch_object($result)){
    $statustranssacao = $obj->StatusTransacao;
?>
    <tr>
    <td nowrap="nowrap" align="center">
    <?  if($obj->TransacaoID!=''){?>
    <select style="width:200px" onchange="alterarStatusFunction(this.options[this.selectedIndex].title);" name="alterarStatus">
        <option selected value="0">- Opções -</option>
        <option disabled="disabled">------------------------------------------</option>
        <? if($statustranssacao!='Aprovado' && $statustranssacao!='Completo'){?><option title="aprovado" value="<?=$obj->Referencia;?>">Marcar como APROVADO</option><? } ?>
        <? if($statustranssacao!='Completo' && $statustranssacao=='Aprovado'){?><option title="completo" value="<?=$obj->Referencia;?>">Marcar como COMPLETO</option><? } ?>
        <? if($statustranssacao!='Cancelado'){?><option title="cancelado" value="<?=$obj->Referencia;?>">Marcar como CANCELADO</option><? } ?>
        <? if($statustranssacao!='Devolvido'){?><option title="devolvido" value="<?=$obj->Referencia;?>">Marcar como DEVOLVIDO</option><? } ?>
    </select>
    <? }else{ ?>
    <span>Transação não iniciada!</span>
    <? } ?>
    </td>
    </tr>
<? } } ?>       
</form>
```

Galera, não consigo fazer esse trem funcionar. As funções do JS funcionam normalmente, o problema é executar a query de acordo com a opção selecionada. Alguém tem alguma dica?

Comment: É tudo um arquivo só ou estão separados?

Comment: Tudo em um arquivo só, não coloquei todo o código aqui pq é bem extenso, então coloquei as partes mais importantes.

Answer (score 0):

O erro está no seu código PHP.
Ao invés de você colocar isso:

```
if($_REQUEST['alterarStatus']){ $alterarStatus = 
trataaspas($_REQUEST['alterarStatus']);}

if($alterarStatus=="aprovado"){

$SQL = "update ps set StatusTransacao='Aprovado' where Referencia = '52'";  

}elseif($alterarStatus=="completo"){
}elseif($alterarStatus=="cancelado"){
}elseif($alterarStatus=="devolvido"){
}
```

Você deve por isso:

```
if($_REQUEST['alterarStatus']){ $alterarStatus = trataaspas($_REQUEST['alterarStatus']);}

    if($alterarStatus=="aprovado"){

        $SQL = "update ps set StatusTransacao='Aprovado' where Referencia = '52'";  

    }elseif($alterarStatus=="completo"){
        $SQL = "update ps set StatusTransacao='completo' where Referencia = '52'";
    }elseif($alterarStatus=="cancelado"){
        $SQL = "update ps set StatusTransacao='cancelado' where Referencia = '52'";
    }elseif($alterarStatus=="devolvido"){
        $SQL = "update ps set StatusTransacao='devolvido' where Referencia = '52'";
    }
```

Comment: Leandro, eu sei que estava faltando as query para as outras opções, eu deixei somente na primeira para testar. O problema é que não funciona, ele não executa a query de nenhuma opção.

Comment: Talvez precise mudar o código, pois cada opção possuí um value diferente, ai não sei como fazer no PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Não está funcionando por que quando você envia o formulário pelo JavaScript, você automaticamente reseta a variável, e depois quando tenta ler ela pelo php, a pagina já recarregou.
Faz o seguinte teste, no form, mude o method para "get".
Esses ifs:

```
if($alterarStatus=="aprovado"){
$SQL = "update ps set StatusTransacao='Aprovado' where Referencia = '52'";  
}elseif($alterarStatus=="completo"){
}elseif($alterarStatus=="cancelado"){
}elseif($alterarStatus=="devolvido"){
}
```

Mude para:

```
if(isset($_GET['alterarStatus'])){ //Verifica se existe, pra nao ficar dando erro
    $status = $_GET['alterarStatus']; //aqui pegamos o valor selecionado por get
}

if($status=="aprovado"){
echo $SQL = "update ps set StatusTransacao='Aprovado' where Referencia = '52'";  

}elseif($status=="completo"){
}elseif($status=="cancelado"){
}elseif($status=="devolvido"){
}
```

Comment: Blz, vou testar e te falo aqui. Uma dúvida, como eu poderia fazer para pegar o valor da option? No caso ele seria substituido em Referencia = '52', por que cada option possuí um value diferente.

Comment: O get pega justamente isso, o value

Comment: Editei sua resposta, ficaria assim no caso?

Comment: Não vai funcionar, como cada option possuí um valor diferente ele não vai conseguir executar a query correta, que no caso e separado por aprovado, completo, cancelado, devolvido. Esses status eu coloquei no atributo title. Como eu poderia fazer?

Comment: No caso, além do valor, você quer passar um id, certo? Pra fazer algo como: "update tabela set situacao = 'completo' where id = 52".
Você quer passar a situação e o id? Se for, dá sim! É só colocar no action o id/referencia, e depois recuperar da mesma forma que fiz com os options. Ficaria assim:
`<form name="formtransacoes" id="formtransacoes" action="<?echo '?'.$obj->Referencia;?>" method="post">`